# How can I easily configure my Neovim to provide a vs code like javascript, html & CSS autocomplete, intellisence & highlighting?

Tags: neovim, filetype-html, filetype-javascript, vscode

I am new to Neovim & overwhelmed by the extremely huge number of ways to configure it, which take hours & have no surity of working for me, as I am using Neovim on my Android via termux (for example I installed LazyVim & after installation I discovered it had failed to install 4-8 packages & gives errors & warnings whenever I run it & does not even show me its opening interface. I have removed it now). So please give me a summarised stepwise way to configure my neovim such that it provides

- HTML, CSS & JS syntax highlighting
- HTML, CSS & JS autocomplete like VS Code
- HTML, CSS & JS intellisence such that i always get a little bit of information when I hover over any js function, js variable, CSS property or html tag
- Emmet

Please answer considering that I am using Neovim on Android not on any PC. I need a minimal configuration to provide me all the above mentioned things in my Neovim on Android.

Comment: I suppose your question is a little too broad for this site, which answers specific questions. Have you tried something and got stuck somewhere?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad which is a great starter you can build your own configuration upon. In my configuration I disabled the LSP stuff on it though and added https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/ which allows me to use Coc Extensions that are easily ported from VSCode Extensions. It made the transition from VSCode easy. If this is still too much, why not using VSCode with https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim instead?

Answer (score 0):

### Frame Challenge

I know you said Android, so I'm assuming VS Code isn't an option, but it sounds like you'd be happier with a computer and VS Code… Vim in general is going to require a learning investment. I highly recommend doing so, but you're the only that can judge whether or not it's worth your time.

If you do, use `vimtutor` and `:help` (the user guide is fantastic).

You'll learn, for example, that

- syntax highlighting and filetype features are available out of the box (`:help usr_05`, `:help usr_06`)
- mostly, so is autocomplete (`:help 20.3`, `:help 24.3`)
- you can use packages to install other plugins, like LSP clients or Emmet-like plugins to try to recreate other experiences (`:help 05.5`).

Read `:help` to learn how to navigate help pages.